# ETW system calls tracing

Tags: c++, winapi, etw

How one could get a process id who generated the system call in ETW? As long as **ProcessID** and **ThreadID** members of event header are = to -1, this can't be used. I heard about activating **CSWitch** flag to capture every single context switch, but that only gives me, **NewThreadId** and **OldThreadId** according the [MOF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964744%28VS.85%29.aspx) class. I want the process id too.

Thanks

Comment: which calls do you wan to trace?

Comment: Basically, all system calls, but I want to know which process from the user space made a call.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. You already see the kernel calls.

Comment: Can't you keep track of which process each thread belongs to?

Comment: @arx yes, I figured out there is an API call to do that, GetProcessIdOfThread.