# Get created/modified/deleted files by a specific process from an event tracing (ETW) session

Tags: windows, events, etl, trace, etw

I've been searching for a solution to get all created/modified and deleted files by a specific process from an event trace (ETW) session (I will process data from an etl file not from a real-time session).

Apparently the simplest solution to get this done was to get the *FileCreate* and *FileDelete* events from [FileIo_Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363885(v=vs.85).aspx) class and map them to the corresponding [DiskIo_TypeGroup1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363705(v=vs.85).aspx) events. However, this solution isn't working for me since I don't receive any **DiskIo_TypeGroup1** events for the corresponding *FileDelete* events, so I can not get the process ID. Also not all *FileCreate* events have an associated **DiskIo_TypeGroup1** event (I think this happens for the empty created files or only for the opened files).

Note: I need **DiskIo_TypeGroup1** mapping because **FileIo_Name** events don't have the *ThreadId* and *ProcessId* members populated - they are set to *(ULONG)-1*. Also, I can not decide which files where just opened or modified without knowing the "file write size". **DiskIo_TypeGroup1** also don't have the *ThreadId* and *ProcessId* (in event header, on newer OS's) members populated, but it has the *IssuingThreadId* structure member from which I can obtain the *ProcessId* mapping to **Thread_TypeGroup1** class events.

So I investigated how the **FileIo_Create** class can help me, and remarked that I can get the *CreateOptions* member which can have the following flags: *(FILE_SUPERSEDE, FILE_CREATE, FILE_OPEN, FILE_OPEN_IF, FILE_OVERWRITE, FILE_OVERWRITE_IF)*. But the initial problem still persists. How can I check if a file was created from scratch instead of being just opened (e.g. in case of *FILE_SUPERSEDE*)?

Maybe I can use the **FileIo_ReadWrite** class to get *Write* event. Like using the **DiskIo_TypeGroup1** class. So, if something was written to a file, then can I suppose that the file was either created or modified?

To find the deleted files I think that the **FileIo_Info** class and *Delete* event are the solution. Guess that I can receive *Delete* events and map them to **FileIo_Name** to get the file names.

Note: The **FileIo_Create**, **FileIo_Info**, **FileIo_ReadWrite** contain information about process id.

Are my suppositions right? What will be the best solution for my problem?

Comment: which language do you use? For .net you can use TraceEvent (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent) to parse the ETL, here you have Events fro all FileIO and DiskIO events in the KernelTraceEventParser class.

Comment: Hi @magicandre1981, I am using C++, but already looked at the [KernelTraceEventParser](http://bcl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Tools/ETW/traceEvent/KernelTraceEventParser.cs) implementation, unfortunately this hasn't solved my problem because *TraceEvent* only parses and formats events in a nicer way, not having any high level processing, like my case of deducing created/modified/deleted files from a specific process. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: what do you mean with high level? any events has a processid, processname property

Comment: Yes you're right, almost all events has a processID except FileIo_Name (or at least i can't get them) and some other events like [TcpIp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364128(v=vs.85).aspx) (see Remarks on the bottom). Another related question can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440639/etw-system-calls-tracing

Also i extracted the ETL with [Tracerpt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732700(v=ws.11).aspx) to see the results [IMG](http://i.imgur.com/pexkJVt.png).

Comment: `using (_source = new ETWTraceEventSource(dataFileName))
{
_kernelTraceEventParser = new KernelTraceEventParser(_source);
_kernelTraceEventParser.FileIODelete += data => { var filename = data.FileName; };
_source.Process();
}`

Comment: I can can get a filename at a FileIO event. I have no idea which issue you have

Comment: Hi @magicandre1981, I will take a deeper look at the KernelTraceEventParser implementation to see what is the difference(since i use directly native API's) or what i have missed, and will come back with details, thank you.

Comment: have you made some progress?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722043/403671

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will share my implemented solution as follow :

1. Created Files:

   - I have stored all **FileIo_Create** events as a pending create operation and waited to receive associated **FileIo_OpEnd** to decide if the file was opened, created, overwritten, or superseded from the *ExtraInfo* structure member.
2. Modified Files:

   - I marked files as dirty for every *Write* event from **FileIo_ReadWrite** and every *SetInfo* event with *InfoClass->FileEndOfFileInformation* and *InfoClass->FileValidDataLengthInformation* from **FileIo_Info**. Finally on *Cleanup* event from **FileIo_SimpleOp** verify if the file was marked as dirty and store as modified.
3. Deleted files:

   - I marked the files as deleted if was opened with the *CreateOptions->FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE* flag from **FileIo_Create** or if a *Delete* event from **FileIo_Info** appears. Finally on *Cleanup* event from **FileIo_SimpleOp** stored the file as deleted.

Also the process id and file name was obtained from the **FileIo_Create** events, more precisely from *OpenPath* structure member and *ProcessId* event header member.

Comment: Nice, but how did you figure out what does each ExtraInfo value mean?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't remember where I got this information from.

But as my code tells, the ExtraInfo value of  *FileIo_OpEnd* associated with *FileIo_Create* contains one of the following values :

`#define FILE_SUPERSEDED                 0x00000000
#define FILE_OPENED                     0x00000001
#define FILE_CREATED                    0x00000002
#define FILE_OVERWRITTEN                0x00000003
#define FILE_EXISTS                     0x00000004
#define FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST             0x00000005`

Comment: @MoeKav please check the above message and see if that helps you.

Comment: @T.Nicolae FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE of CreateOptions was re-named to FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE

Comment: @T.Nicolae How can you match a FileIOCreate event with FileIOOperationEnd event? FileIOOpEndTraceData does not have FileName or FileKey properties

Comment: @T.Nicolae I found out that IrpPtr property can be used to match the events  


"FileIo events are logged at the beginning of the operation. OpEnd events can be enabled separately to indicate the end of those operations. Irp can be used to correlate the begin and end events."

Comment: @AhmedOsama indeed I matched the events by IrpPtr