# How to check if file someone views/opens a file?

Tags: c#, winapi, filesystemwatcher

The requirement here is to monitor confidential files in a particular folder using C#. So let's say I have "C:/Secrets", the program should monitor this folder for any read access or data being copied from this folder.

I tried using [FileSystemWatcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1), but based on my understanding we can only monitor for Changed, Created, Deleted events using this. Below is the example code from documentation.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            watcher.Path = args[1];

            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
            // the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnChanged;
            watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) =>
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e) =>
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.OldFullPath} renamed to {e.FullPath}");
}
```

How can we monitor a folder for Read access? And is it possible to monitor Copy action?

Comment: Are you creating a sort of auditing mechanism? Have you already checked Audit File System of Windows? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-file-system

Comment: Your observation is wrong. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged) explains *"`OnChanged` is called when changes are made to the size, system attributes, last write time, **last access time**, or security permissions of a file or directory in the directory being monitored."* Though that requires, that the filesystem records the last access time. Which is disabled by default on all supported versions of Windows.

Comment: you need [minifilter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/filter-manager-concepts)

Comment: You could try the  Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent nuget package, like demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722043/403671

Comment: @user2297037 - Yes, need to have auditing mechanism, but need to achieve this programmatically, so we specify a folder and auditing should be turned on for it with logs.

Answer (score -2):

use File.GetLastAccessTime

Here's a link to the documentation:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastaccesstime?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The last access time is updated only *after* closing the handle referencing the file. This doesn't allow you to monitor read *access*. And it's disabled by default, starting with Windows Vista. Even if enabled, a program can actively [disable updating the last access time](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111010-00/?p=9433).