# An unknown process is overwriting the contents of my application's files with 0x00 bytes

Tags: c, windows, winapi

### Summary

I have developed a Windows application that saves configuration files every time it runs. Rarely, when reading those files back in, I discover that they are filled with zeroes (0x00 bytes). I've determined that **they are zeroed out long after my application has exited by an unknown process**. What could this process be, and why is it zeroing out my files?

### Details

Although rare, I am not the only one having this problem. For a broader perspective, see: [Very strange phenomenon: output file filled or truncated with binary zeros. What could cause that?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c6096af-34e4-4dd5-bea0-ab130e498e3e/very-strange-phenomenon-output-file-filled-or-truncated-with-binary-zeros-what-could-cause-that)

- I'm using Visual Studio 2017 C++, but files are opened with `fopen()`, written to with a single `fwrite()` call, and closed using `fclose()`. All calls are error-checked (other affected people report that they use `CFile`).
- I confirm the validity of each save by immediately reading it back in and checking file contents (via hashes/checksums). **I'm certain that the file is indeed written to the disk correctly.**
- At some point before the next invocation of my application, some unknown process writes to the file and fills it with zeroes (the file size/length stays the same, but all bytes are 0x00).

**How I know this**: Every time I save a file, I also save in the Registry the file's 3 `GetFileTime()` times (Creation, Last Access, Last Write). When I detect a corruption (zero-out), I compare the current `GetFileTime()` times with the ones stored in the Registry. **In all cases, the "Last Access" and "Last Write" times have changed.**

Something has written to my files a random amount of time later (anywhere between 10 minutes and 24+ hours, although that number is obviously also skewed by how frequently the application is executed).

Some more information:

- I can't reproduce the problem on my development machine -- all instances are on clients (application users) through remote logging and crash reports (I've been trying to solve this for months). This makes it impossible to run the application in a controlled test harness (e.g. debugger, procmon, security policy's "Audit object access", etc)
- Upon detecting a zero-out, I immediately log the currently running process list (using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` -- no services). However, **there isn't any common process that stands out**. If I exclude processes also running on my development machine, then the next most common process (it's a Windows process) is only executing on 50% of the clients.  Avast antivirus (a potential culprit) only exists on 35% of clients.
- I've tried bracketing each save with "canary" files that are saved immediately prior and after the actual file. Canary files contain plain text, random binary data, or actual application data (encrypted or not). They are all zeroed out regardless.
- Whenever multiple of my files get zeroed out, then they ALL get zeroed out simultaneously (their "Last Access"/"Last Write" times are within 100ms across all files).
- I've tried compiling the application both with Visual Studio 2017 using CL and also Visual Studio 2019 using LLVM. They are both zeroed out.
- Zero-outs still happen with a frequency of about 1 per day for every 1000 daily application executions (i.e., daily active users).
- Zero-outs are random and once-only. It could be months before it occurs for a given client. And after it does, it never happens again.
- Affects both Windows 7 and Windows 10, even if no antivirus is installed.

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://superuser.com/questions/521476/detect-what-process-is-changing-a-file-on-windows) to try to find out what process is overwriting the file?

Comment: @Toothless204 Good thinking -- however I can't reproduce the 'bug' locally and it's very rare, so it's practically impossible to use such tools on remote clients . I've amended the original post to say so.

Comment: You can write your own low level tool (users would see nothing) with something similar at my sample code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722043/403671 or use windows file auditing

Comment: You could also set a SACL on the file that generates an audit event when somebody writes to the file.

Comment: @RaymondChen I can't reproduce the problem locally, so on each client computer I'd need to remotely (a) set the SACL (b) modify the Local Security Policy and (c) access the Event Viewer for results. Can all of this be done programmatically?

Comment: It sounds like you've excluded a problem in your app, so this doesn't seem like a programming problem per se. Therefore it may be more appropriate to post this on another site like Super User.

Comment: @Xaxx and NONE of your affected clients are willing to run procmon on their system for a few days to find the culprit? Set a filter for the file you are interested in, and then let it run in the background until the file is altered.

Comment: @Xaxx if you go the SACL route, you don't need remote access to EventViewer, your app can monitor the Event Log directly watching for the audit event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can't know or predict in advance which 1 in a 1000 users will be affected by this problem, or when. I'd have to ask ALL users to run these tests continuously for several weeks, and that's not practical. As for Event Viewer: recall that the zeroing-out happens while the app is NOT running.

Comment: Raymond/Remy, maybe write an answer covering how to set up the SACL and check the log afterwards? Although I agree with the comment that superuser.com would be the better site. In any case this sort of issue is a horror story for developers

Comment: I had a similar(ish) situation once where my app's data file would randomly be deleted, it did turn out to be antivirus in that case

Comment: Sometimes, after a power blackout shutdown my PC, the last few files that were written to and not yet flushed to disk, were zeroed out.