# Find out what is touching web.config file in IIS website

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

Is there a way to verify what is touching a `web.config` file that is restarting a site? Procmon doesnt work because its a production server.

This is on `Windows Server 2012 R2` and doesnt have any anti virus software on it but the site randomly restarts around 1 time a week.

The `application_end` method in `Global.asax` says config changes so it wasnt an app pool recycle because those are done at a specific time.

No one is touching the config files and I want to know who or what is?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.applicationshutdownreason?view=netframework-4.8

[image]

**Logging**

```
    CONFIG change
    HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
    CONFIG change
    HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.OnConfigurationChanged(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigChanged(InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.OnStreamChanged(String streamname)
   at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications()
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com so that you can get action plans suitable for production environment. In short, file access audit log might help, but Process Monitor might still be needed in certain cases (with special settings to minimize its impact on server performance).

Comment: Process Monitor basically hangs my site.

Comment: If you simply open Process Monitor and leave it running there, then hanging your site or even the whole server is what I expect. Like I said, you need action plans that are tailored for production environment so only experienced support professionals can suggest.

Comment: So I just post something on Microsoft support with my question? Are you this capable person?

Comment: If you think it's another process, you can write a small tool, using the same approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722043/403671 , modify it slightly like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/TaEpetqY and this will tell you what process changes the file.

Comment: Does it show who changed it, or who just touches it.   I dont think anything is being changed, but something maybe trying to access it updating the access date.  Its the only think I can think of. I do have an audit setup on it and nothing sticks out with writing to it. before the restart happens.

Comment: There are many low level events that you can use (ex: FileIOSetInfo will detect last write change). But changing last access time won't restart the web app. You can just try it, it's easy

Comment: How about this idea: exclusively lock the config file before the IIS start, start IIS, and see if something will fail and report an error in the Windows Log

Comment: Will the site even start with an exclusive lock on it?

Comment: Maybe not, but I would still try and see if it will produce any clues..

Comment: It won’t, this is a random thing and can happen after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I use these **steps to protect and secure** my website,

1- Make all files read-only and only Upload Folder has read/write access.

2- Do not run IIS or SQL using administrator. If you are already running it as administrator stop and re-run with user.

3- You don't need an antivirus, Check processes and configure Ransomware protection and restart server, If any process will try to change files it will stop it's access

4- Check event logs for the reasons.

Comment: I need to write to my config file myself, how can I of read only?

Comment: attrib +r <FIle/Folder Name>
This will make the target file read-only. Still if you want to change ownership go to file properties and visit security tab and click change.
If you want to remove read only attribute then run
attrib -r  <FIle/Folder Name>