# Disable recycling for configuration and alternative ways to do it for IIS and AppPool

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server, application-pool, recycle

We are having weird configuration change errors that happen and we can't tell why.  We have tried just about everything to figure out what is happening.  We now want to stop the site from recycling the app domain when this happens.

If we set the setting below as `True` for the `Disable recycling for configuration`, what is the best way to recycle the app domain when we push new code or touch the web.config file when this is changed?

Also we have recycling of the app pool done ever night, will this clear stuff out with this setting set to `True` like before?

[image]

Comment: Are you observing weird ASP.NET AppDomain reloads or IIS application pool recycle? If you cannot tell the differences, please dig into that first.

Comment: Its AppDomain reloads, there is a configuration change and the site reloads.  Something is touching my configuration files or something else is happening. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324302/find-out-what-is-touching-web-config-file-in-iis-website?noredirect=1#comment124469342_70324302

Comment: Then don't waste your time on IIS side, as none of the application pool settings contribute to that. If ASP.NET RTW tracing does not give you enough hints on what might be wrong, you will have to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to involve Microsoft directly.

Comment: How do I open a support ticket on that site? Do they actually help fix something like this also?

Comment: The actual steps might be different in different regions of the world, so by principle 1) use that site to find the support hotline number for your type of business (personal/small/large) and country. 2) make a call to go through your product purchase record. 3) Microsoft support team will decide whether to accept the case and offer assistance. They can help analyze such tough issues to get you started in most scenarios.

Comment: When we do this it gets overridden by security patches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went the route found in this article with warming up an app pool, and not recycling on any config changes.  This has been so beneficial to us that we recommend it if you are having issues.  We have had 0 downtime in a year when we switch to this setup.

https://www.leansentry.com/guide/reset-restart-recycle-iis/max-application-pool-warmup